# How to make aggregations in TypeOrm

Tags: javascript, postgresql, aggregate-functions, typeorm

I need to get lists of interests with data aboit it and count customers that subscibed to interest

I have many-to-one relation between interests and customers.
This is what only might to do

```
    const list = await this.interestRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('interest')
        .leftJoinAndSelect("interest.translations", "translations")
        .leftJoinAndSelect("interest.customers", "customers")
        .getMany()
```

And this is the result:

```
list [
  Interest {
    id: 'YJnu_8bpzMSrFiztDl1zH',
    creationDate: 2022-12-19T16:49:55.090Z,
    countryCode: 'LTU',
    rank: 2,
    status: 'active',
    translations: [ [InterestTranslation], [InterestTranslation] ],
    customers: [ [Customer] ]
  },
  Interest {
    id: '-h1UPpOSkw4TqcTc7F5Ej',
    creationDate: 2022-12-19T16:57:47.718Z,
    countryCode: 'USA',
    rank: 1,
    status: 'active',
    translations: [ [InterestTranslation], [InterestTranslation] ],
    customers: []
  }
]
```

But i want to count the customers, not get all of them, because it could be thouthands of them and it will affect on  request duration.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly you need put this

```
.loadRelationCountAndMap('interest.customers', 'interest.customers')
```

instead of

```
.leftJoinAndSelect("interest.customers", "customers")
```